# My signup button disappears while filling out my password on a form

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

This is a two-part question.

Part 1. The `passConfirm` function that I currently have is there to make sure that the password and confirming password values match. Right now, when I type in my password the button disappears. The purpose of this function is to display a message while the user is creating a password and confirming it, that the password does or does not match.  Does anyone know why that is happening based on the code I have?

Part 2. Is there a way to refactor my `passConfirm` function? I tried doing it by adding it to the `validateForm` function (Please see commented code for my example). It wasn't working tho.

```js
function printError(elemId, message) {
  document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = message;
}

function validateForm() {
  event.preventDefault();
  var name = document.regForm.FullName.value;
  var email = document.regForm.email.value;
  var phone = document.regForm.phone.value;
  var password = document.regForm.Password.value;
  var confirmPassword = document.regForm.ConfirmPassword.value;
  const phoneno = /^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$/;

  var nameError = emailError = phoneError = passwordError = true;
  //Empty name input error message
  if (name == "") {
    printError("nameError", "Please enter your name")
  }
  //Empty email input error message
  if (email == "") {
    printError("emailError", "Please enter a valid email")

  }
  //Empty phone input error message
  if (phone == "") {
    printError("phoneError", "Please enter your phone numnber")
  }
  //Non valid phone number error messsage
  if (phone.match(phoneno)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    printError("phoneError", "Please enter a valid phone number")
  }
  //Empty Password input
  if (password == "") {
    printError("passwordError", "Please enter a password")
  }
  //Empty Cofirm Password input
  if (confirmPassword == "") {
    printError("confirmpassError", "Please confirm your password")
  }

  //I tried refactoring the passConfirm function and additing it here. 
  //if (password.match(confirmPassword)) {
  //  printPass("matchingPassword", "Passwords match")
  //  document.getElementById("matchingPassword").style.color = "green";
  //} else {
  //  printPass("matchingPassword", "Passwords do no match")
  //  document.getElementById("matchingPassword").style.color = "red";
  //}
};


var passConfirm = function() {  
  if (document.getElementById("Password").value ==    document.getElementById("ConfirmPassword").value) {   
    document.getElementById("matchingPassword").style.color = "green";   
    document.getElementById("matchingPassword").style.fontWeight = "Heavy";   
    document.getElementById("matchingPassword").innerHTML = "Passwords match!"  
  } else {   
    document.getElementById("matchingPassword").style.color = "red";   
    document.getElementById("matchingPassword").style.fontWeight = "Heavy";   
    document.getElementById("matchingPassword").innerHTML = "Passwords do NOT match!"  
  } 
}
```

```css
fieldset {
  width: 420px;
  height: 950px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello, please register!</h1>
<div class="container">
  <form name="regForm" class="form" onsubmit="return validateForm(event)">
    <fieldset>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Full Name</label></br>
        <input name="FullName" type="text" placeholder="John Doe" id="FullName" />
        <span class="error" id="nameError"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Email</label></br>
        <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="johndoe@email.com" id="Email" />
        <span class="error" id="emailError"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Phone Number</label></br>
        <input name="phone" type="tel" placeholder="(123) 456-7890" id="PhoneNumber" />
        <span class="error" id="phoneError"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Password</label></br>
        <input name="Password" id="Password" type="Password" placeholder="Password" onchange='passConfirm();' />
        <span class="error" id="passwordError"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <label>Confirm Password</label></br>
        <input name="ConfirmPassword" id="ConfirmPassword" type="Password" placeholder="Confirm Password" onchange='passConfirm();' />
        <span class="error" id="confirmpassError"></span>
      </div>
      <span id="matchingPassword">
              <button type="submit" value="submit">Sign Me Up!</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button disappears because you use InnerHTML method to display the message, which overrides it. Though your logic works after passwords match when you press enter, you lose your button element. It is better to use a separate div or paragraph tag to display your message and keep your button as it is since it's part of the form.

Here is the change you can try

```
<span id="matchingPassword">
              <button type="submit" value="submit">Sign Me Up!</button></span>
              <p id="message"></p>
        </fieldset>

var passConfirm = function() {  
  if (document.getElementById("Password").value ==    document.getElementById("ConfirmPassword").value) {   
    document.getElementById("message").style.color = "green";   
    document.getElementById("message").style.fontWeight = "Heavy";   
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Passwords match!"  
  } else {   
    document.getElementById("message").style.color = "red";   
    document.getElementById("message").style.fontWeight = "Heavy";   
    document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = "Passwords match!"  
  } 
}
```